# Creating a custom rule in jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I would like to add a custom rule to jQuery validate, and while I have checked the docs I have not been able to find out how to do this.

I want to loop over a set of hidden form fields. If the fields value is "X", then I would like to append an error class to a field.

So essentially this, but added as a rule to jQuery validate.

```
$(".myHiddenField").each( function() {
   if($(this).val() == "x") {
    $(this).closest(".foo").appendClass("error");
   }
});
```

Comment: you want loop this input， you should  $(".myHiddenField input").each( function() {})

Comment: Areschen, I am not asking how to select the element - rather how to implement this within the jQuery validate fw.

Answer (score 12):

You may use `addMethod()`

```
$.validator.addMethod('yourRuleName', function (value, element, param) {
    //Your Validation Here

    return isValid; // return bool here if valid or not.
}, 'Your error message!');


$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        field1: {
            yourRuleName: true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Let me give this a try. Thanks!

Comment: English please..You should not use your local language so your comment may help other people too.. =)

Comment: Ayon sa [translate.google](http://translate.google.com.ph/#auto/en/Ano%20yun%3F%20kahit%20anong%20pangalan%20nung%20yourRuleName%3F%20or%20nakadepende%20dun%20sa%20class%2C%20attribute%20or%20id%3F):What's that? yourRuleName whatever name? or dun depend on class, attribute or id?

Comment: Ohh.. Yup, it is the name of your validation rule, you may use any name you want.

Comment: I am still not following. In your example, how is it applying the error class to the closest field?

Comment: @JasonWells The `element` parameter serves as the field you are validating.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show some custom error messages without adding an actual rule then you can use the [showErrors()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.showErrors) method, but if you are working on a hidden field it may not work

```
var validator = $( "<form-selector>" ).validate();

var errors = {};
$(".myHiddenField").each( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.val() == "x") {
        errors[$this.attr('name')] = 'Some error message';
    }
});

validator.showErrors(errors);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.validator.addMethod("NOTx", function(element,value) {
    return  value != "x";
}, 'warning word"!');
```

Comment: It's very bad to show how to create some customization but not to show how to use it. The answer from Nikko Reyes is way better than yours.